# How can I set the Rmarkdown output template file dynamically in the YAML header as part of a package?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I've got a package that saves data.frames as formatted tables in Word files, but I'm having trouble with using anything other than the default for the Word template. Inside my function, I call on `rmarkdown::render` with something like this:

```
rmarkdown::render(system.file("rmarkdown/templates/savemytable/skeleton/skeleton.Rmd",
                                package="mypackage")
                    quiet = TRUE)
```

Here's the YAML header for the skeleton.Rmd file that this calls on:

```
---
date: "Compiled on `r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
output: word_document
---
```

I would like to include a template Word file in my package that would allow people to save this in a landscape orientation, so I have saved a template Word file in the `inst` folder with a path like this:

```
 inst/Word/landscape_report_template.dotx
```

If I run this:

```
 system.file("Word/landscape_report_template.dotx",
                              package="mypackage")
```

that gets me the file path to landscape_report_template.dotx, so it seems like that part is working fine. However, I can't figure out how to adjust the output part of the YAML header to take anything but a hard-coded file path. This works:

```
 output: 
  word_document:
        reference_docx: "C:/Users/myname/mypackage/inst/Word/landscape_report_template.dotx"
```

But that obviously won't work for other users. I have tried the following, which all result in `"Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 99".`

```
 output: 
  word_document:
        reference_docx: !r system.file("Word/landscape_report_template.dotx",
                          package="mypackage")


 output: 
  word_document:
        reference_docx: "`r system.file("Word/landscape_report_template.dotx",
                          package="mypackage")`"
```

and a few other variations on places to insert " or ` to try to get what I want. **How can I dynamically specify the path of the reference_docx file?**

**UPDATE:** This seems to be strangely difficult to do natively with rmarkdown. I've seen a few brief and not terribly illustrative examples using `rmarkdown::yaml_front_matter` to extract what the various YAML parameters are and then change the ones you want, but I don't get how you then put that information *back* into the skeleton.Rmd file in a package, e.g,.

```
 yaml_meta <- rmarkdown::yaml_front_matter(system.file("rmarkdown/templates/savemytable/skeleton/skeleton.Rmd", 
      package="mypackage"))

  # Modify YAML
  yaml_meta$output$word_document$reference_docx <- 
      system.file("Word/landscape_report_template.dotx",
                          package="mypackage")
```

But then what? Would you overwrite the package skeleton.Rmd file?!? That seems crazy to me.

Comment: You should take a look at the `knitr::rocco` help page.  It gives an example of doing something like what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your own function that wraps a call to `rmarkdown::render` with options specified to give your template.  I think this might do it, though I haven't tested it:

```
with_landscape_template = function(input) {
  rmarkdown::render(input, 
    word_document(
            reference_docx = system.file("Word/landscape_report_template.dotx",
                                         package="mypackage")))
}
```

Comment: This was EXACTLY the missing piece I needed! Thanks! The only thing I would add for clarification if anyone else has this issue is that I left the YAML output as `output: word_document` and didn't try adding anything for reference_docx there; only inside the render call.

Comment: Yes, whatever is in the YAML `output` spec is completely ignored in this approach.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this process needs a word document, not a word template. Please try to put a word document (docx) instead of a word template (dotx) as the reference document.

```
output: 
  word_document:
        reference_docx: "C:/Users/myname/mypackage/inst/Word/landscape_report_template.docx"
```

should work in your case.

But there are two requirements:

(A) You must generate this document through pandoc only. It means you have to first put some dummy content in one RMarkdown document, then render it as a word document. This document can be your reference_docx.

(B) You must use in-built styles in Microsoft Word. Once you render the document in the step above, you can change the in-built styles (e.g., heading1, heading2, etc.) in the rendered document.

If you still face any problem, ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks, @Eva, but I have actually found that using the dotx file works fine and it also works fine if the Word file I'm using as a template was generated with Word rather than pandoc as long as I supply an absolute file path. The problem I have is getting around the need for an absolute path.

Comment: Check this book chapter for more reference. https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/word-template.html